# Could a molecular cloud be breathable?

Tags: life, deep-space, interstellar-medium

Molecular clouds in deep space are fascinating objects. Various organic molecules have been found there (including alcohol, heh heh).

So if one of these clouds contained about 20% of oxygen, would it be possible to breathe it in the inner regions of the cloud?

Comment: The percent oxygen is not the important number for respiration, instead what matters is the partial pressure of oxygen which needs to be around 0.2 atm.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not a chance.

Those "clouds" are a vacuum, but just a vacuum that has a few more particles than outside those "clouds".  The density of those "clouds" around [1–100 particles per cm³](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_cloud#Giant_molecular_clouds).  You can't breathe it at all.

You may want to look at this Scaling in Density page at [Princeton University](https://www.astro.princeton.edu/~dns/teachersguide/ScDensAct.html):

Earth: 5.5 gram/cm³, $1.8 \cdot 10^{23}$ molecules per cm³,

Earth atmosphere: 0.0012 g/cm³ ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth)),

Molecular Clouds: $2 \cdot 10^{-22}$ gram/cm³, 10 molecules per cm³.